# How to verify method calls in different CoroutineScope in unit tests with Mockk?

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin-coroutines, mockk, mockk-verify

I am trying to verify that method in dependency object is called, but since it happens in different CoroutineScope coVerify always fails.

**How to verify that someMethod() is called?**

Here is my code:

SUT:

```
class SomeClass(
    private val coroutineScope: CoroutineScope,
    private val someDependency: SomeDependency
) {
    fun run() {
        coroutineScope.launch {
            someDependency.someMethod()
        }
    }
}
```

Dependency:

```
class SomeDependency {
    fun someMethod() {
        println("SomeDependency.someMethod")
    }
}
```

Test(always fails):

```
class SomeClassTest {


    @MockK(relaxed = true)
    private lateinit var someDependency: SomeDependency

    private val testScope = TestScope()
    private lateinit var someClass: SomeClass

    @Before
    fun setup() {
        MockKAnnotations.init(this)
        someClass = SomeClass(
            testScope,
            someDataSource
        )
    }

    @Test
    fun `when run, should call someDependency someMethod`() = runTest {
        someClass.run()
        coVerify { someDependency.someMethod() }
    }

}
```

Comment: You can follow the [Google Developer documentation](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/coroutines/test). You will need to call `runTest` and pass a test dispatcher

Comment: @Eselfar thank you. If you compose answer, I'll mark it as correct

Answer (score 0):

Found how to use same scope for SUT class and test itself:

```
class SomeClassTest {

    private var someDependency: SomeDependency = mockk(relaxed = true)

    @Test
    fun `when run, should call someDependency someMethod`() = runTest {
        val someClass = SomeClass(
            this,
            someDependency
        )
        someClass.run()
        advanceUntilIdle()
        verify { someDependency.someMethod() }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to use test coroutine rule

Rule:

```
class TestCoroutineRule(
    val testCoroutineDispatcher: TestCoroutineDispatcher = TestCoroutineDispatcher(),
    val testCoroutineScope: TestCoroutineScope = TestCoroutineScope(testCoroutineDispatcher)
) : TestWatcher() {

    override fun starting(description: Description) {
        super.starting(description)
        Dispatchers.setMain(testCoroutineDispatcher)
    }

    override fun finished(description: Description) {
        super.finished(description)
        testCoroutineDispatcher.cleanupTestCoroutines()
        Dispatchers.resetMain()
    }
}
```

Test:

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalCoroutinesApi::class)
class SomeClassTest2 {

    @get:Rule
    val testCoroutineRule = TestCoroutineRule()

    private var someDependency: SomeDependency = mockk(relaxed = true)
    private lateinit var someClass: SomeClass

    @Before
    fun setUp() {
        someDependency = mockk(relaxed = true)
        someClass = SomeClass(testCoroutineRule.testCoroutineScope, someDependency)
    }

    @Test
    fun `when run, should call someDependency someMethod`() = runTest {
        someClass.run()
        advanceUntilIdle()
        verify { someDependency.someMethod() }
    }

}
```